# Is this Fibonacci sequence function recursive?

Tags: haskell, recursion

Consider the following (Haskell) code:

```
fib=0:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

A coworker is trying to assert that this is not a recursive function because `fib` is simply a list that defines itself with itself and that is somehow different than a function that does the same.  I think he's smoking crack.

What do you think?

Comment: printf "Oh no, a function with zero arguments, we can't have that!" or die;

Comment: `zipWith` is the recursive function, and `fib` refers to its result. There's nothing magical or non-recursive about it. (The answers below that claim there "is no function" are as confused as your coworker.)

Comment: Your coworker friend is picking nits. It's technically a recursively defined *value*, not a function.

Comment: Piet, your definitions are non-standard.  Don't assume everyone's wrong because they're all using the same definitions, which happen to not match yours.

Comment: Carl: I'm not sure what you're referring to, but recursive functions and recursive data structures are pretty well-defined in Haskell. See any number of papers and writings about ["Tying the Knot"](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot) and related topics.

Comment: @Piet: you keep linking to that article, but it has no bearing on this conversation. We're not talking about recursively defined *data structures*, we're talking about recursively defined *data*. Or if you prefer, we're talking about recursively defined *values*, not recursively defined *types*.

Comment: pelotom: That article is precisely about recursively defined data/values (and not about recursive types, which are a wholly different topic).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The fibonacci definition with zipWith is not a recursive function, in fact there is no function involved, fib is a list (data) that is lazily self-defined, utilizing Haskell's lazy semantic. In a sense, you can call it recursive list or recursive data; but not recursive function.

It may be difficult to wrap your head around recursive list since very little programming languages have anything close, but you'll notice that in Haskell all functions takes exactly one paramater. `fib` does not take any parameter, because it's not a function. Since there is no function involved, you can't have recursive function.

Your coworker isn't smoking crack, he's enlightened (or smoking crack, if that's your definition of enlightenment).

Comment: This is simply wrong: `zipWith` is a recursive function defining the sequence. `fib` is not a recursive list: it is a plain, non-recursive list referring to the *result of evaluating the recursive function `zipWith`*. (Yes, Haskell also supports recursive data, but this refers to definitions like `xs = 1:2:3:xs`, not to question's example.)

Comment: @Piet Delport: `fib` appears on the right hand side of its own definition.... what word do you use for that? I call that "recursive". Neither the recursiveness nor functionalness (functionality?) of `zipWith` is being called into question here.

Comment: pelotom: In Haskell, there is a fundamental difference between recursive *data* and recursive *functions*.  Recursive data is when a data structure concretely refers back to its own constructors, as happens when you say `xs = 1:2:3:xs`: the final cons refers back to the initial one, forming a cycle. There are many different ways to achieve this kind of data recursion: see [Tying the Knot](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Tying_the_Knot). Recursive functions, on the other hand, are like `zipWith`. They may or may not define recursive data structures, too, but in this case, `fib` is not.

Comment: @Piet: `xs = 1:2:3:xs` is a self-referential definition, as is `fib=0:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)`. they're both recursive data. What's the problem?

Comment: pelotom: No, `xs` is recursive data without any function, `fib` is *non-recursive* data generated by a recursive function.

Comment: @Piet: the fact that `fib` makes use of `zipWith` in its definition is neither here nor there. `fib` is most certainly recursive data, as attested to by the fact that it is *defined in terms of itself*.  See those 2 instances of `fib` on the RHS of the equation? That means it's defined in terms of itself, e.g. it is recursive. I don't know how many different ways I can restate this basic point.

Comment: pelotom: The `zipWith` *function* is defined in terms of itself. The recursion never escapes to become part of the list structure: if it did, the list would repeat (and it's obvious that Fibonacci sequence does not repeat). Rather than continue a pointless argument of definitions, i would recommend reading more about the topic of circular and self-referential data structures in Haskell: it's rich and rewarding beyond just this question.

Comment: *"The recursion never escapes to become part of the list structure: if it did, the list would repeat (and it's obvious that Fibonacci sequence does not repeat)"* Uh, what? Since when does recursion imply repetition?

Comment: pelotom: Recursive *data* (e.g. `xs = 1:2:3:xs`) is data that refers to itself, implying *data-level* repetition. Recursive *functions* (e.g. `zipWith`) are functions that refer to themselves, implying *function-level* repetition. (Recursive *types* are types that refer to themselves, implying *type-level* repetition... you get the idea.) Each of these examples of recursion (data, function, type) are completely distinct and orthogonal, and each of them implies repetition / self-reference / recurrence at their own respective level of abstraction, independent of the others.

Comment: @Piet Delport: Recursive data is data that is defined with reference to itself; a recursive data has the general form of: `recd = a1 : a2 : ... : an : (f recd)`. The case of `xs = 1 : 2 : 3 : xs` is only a special case when `f x = x`. Therefore `fib` is a recursive data when `f x = zipWith (+) x (tail x)`. That `f` internally uses a recursive function (e.g. `zipWith`) is totally irrelevant.

Answer (score 11):

My, what a rat's nest of subtle terminological distinctions. What is "this"?

```
fib=0:1:zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)
```

It is not a recursive function. It is not recursive data. It is a recursive definition.

What is being defined?

```
fib
```

What type of thing is `fib`, according to this definition?

```
[Integer]
```

A list of integers (or perhaps a list of any old numeric stuff).

Is `fib` a function? No, it is a list. Is `fib` recursively defined? Yes. Would `fib` be recursively defined if we replaced `zipWith` by a nonrecursive function of the same type (e.g. `\ f xs ys -> xs`)? Yes, although it would be a different recursively defined list.

Is `fib` a cyclic list? No. Does "recursive data structure" mean "cyclic data structure"? Not according to Hoare's paper, "Recursive Data Structures": http://portal.acm.org/book_gateway.cfm?id=63445&type=pdf&bookpath=%2F70000%2F63445%2Fcb-p217-hoare.pdf&coll=&dl=&CFID=15151515&CFTOKEN=6184618

In a typed setting, "recursive data structure" means no more or less than "inhabitant of a recursively defined type". Correspondingly `"fred"` is a recursive data structure, even though it is not recursively defined, and indeed it can be acted upon by recursive functions such as `++`.

The phrase "recursive function" means "recursively defined function". The phrase "recursive value" means "recursively defined value", such as exist in nonstrict languages: strict languages have the "value recursion" problem.

And if you think that's pedantic, try defining `fib` that way in a *total* programming language, and you'll discover that the notion of "recursive definition" splits into "definition by structural recursion" (consuming data in a way which stops) and "definition by guarded corecursion" (producing data in a way which goes), and that `fib` is of the latter variety. In that setting, the productivity of `fib` depends crucially on the laziness of `zipWith`. In the Haskell setting, of course, you don't need to worry about any of that stuff to figure out what sort of definition something is, just to figure out whether it has half a chance of actually working.

Answer (score 9):

It's recursive. You can tell because the name on the LHS of the `=` also appears on the RHS.

It is however *not* a function. You can tell because the type of `fib` does not contain a `->`.

Comment: It’s been a long time since I’ve last used Haskell. Is using the function constructor a hard requirement to make a function? I can’t find a definite statement in the Haskell report but the function type is lexically defined as `type ::= btype [-> type]`, i.e. the function constructor followed by another type is optional. However, later it says that “A function type has the form `t1 -> t2` …”. [[source](http://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch4.html#x10-620004)]

Comment: `fib` is not the function, `zipWith` is.

Comment: @Piet: But that was not the question. The OP specifically says "this Fibonacci sequence function", so he's clearly not asking about zipWith (unless you're saying zipWith is "Fibonacci sequence function").

Comment: sepp2k: Yes, that is what's confusing people. In Haskell terms, `zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)` is the Fibonacci sequence function in the above code. `fib`, in this case, is merely a reference to the (non-recursive) list being *generated* by the aforementioned recursive function.

Comment: @Piet: But `zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)` is also not a function. `zipWith` is a function, `zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)` is the result of applying that function.

Comment: sepp2k: No, `zipWith (+) fib (tail fib)` is a *function application*, and it does not become a result until evaluated. (This may seem like nit-picking, but it's a very deep and important distinction at the very heart of Haskell: a function application may always result in ⊥, and the whole point of non-strict evaluation in Haskell is to allow such ⊥-valued function applications, without evaluating them to their (fatal) result unless strictly necessary.)

Comment: @Piet: Well, fine, but a function application is still not the same as a function.

Comment: sepp2k: Right.  (But that's besides the point of the question being a recursive function definition of the Fibonacci sequence.)

Comment: @Piet: No, it's not besides the point at all. As you said yourself, the question was whether a recursive function is being defined here. Since the only thing being defined here is `fib` and `fib` is not a function, the answer to that is clearly no.

Comment: sepp2k: Now you're just being obtuse: there is no `fib` without the recursive function that is its body. (And no one asked whether `fib` was a function: the question was whether "the function [is] recursive", and `zipWith` is the only function there.)

Comment: There is definitely somebody being obtuse here.

Answer (score 3):

The example you've given is recursive. But the Fibonacci sequence by nature doesn't have to be. There are [iterative versions of the algorithm](https://www.scriptol.com/programming/fibonacci.php), and even [explicit functions](https://web.archive.org/web/20170829141954/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/52686.html).

Comment: Iteration is just a special case of recursion, and generating a sequence will always be recursive in some sense, for hopefully obvious reasons. The formula to compute single terms independently, however, is not itself recursive (although it uses functions that will probably be calculated recursively).

Answer (score 3):

Since most answers support your coworker with respect to the *function* part of: "`fib` is *not* a recursive function." I'd like to elaborate on on the recursive part Conor McBride hinted at in his answer.

The definition given for `fib` is *not* recursive, it is *co-recursive*.

Co-recursion looks a lot like recursion in that, as many posters have pointed out, the LHS of the definition appears on the RHS too. But there is no base case. Recursion and corecursion "run in opposite directions".

The above definition of `fib` starts from the initial values 0 and 1 and moves "up" from there and keeps on going. 
On the other hand a recursive definition of, say (a function calculating) the n-th Fibonacci number

```
fib' 0 = 0
fib' 1 = 1
fib' n = fib' (n-1) + fib' (n-2)
```

walks "downwards" from the n-th number until it reaches the base cases and there stops.

I guess this vindicates the crackhead in both points :-)

---

For further reading check out the wikipedia article on [Corecursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corecursion) and the links there. If you can get you hands on it, Chapter 10 of *The Haskell Road to Logic, Maths and Programming* by Kees Doets and Jan van Eijck may be worth a peek.

Answer (score 2):

He's on crack - the above function is clearly recursive.

Comment: sepp2k: `zipWith` is a function.

Comment: @Piet: The question was whether `fib` was a recursive function, not whether `zipWith` was.

Comment: sepp2k: The question was whether "the following code" was a recursive function, and it clearly is. The fact that `fib` only refers to the result of the recursive function is besides the point, and does not change the fact that the body is a recursive function.

Answer (score 2):

Aside from the Haskell implementation here, the Fibonacci Numbers are a sequence defined by a recurrence relation.  Mathematically speaking, each term is defined as a *function* of the preceding terms.  Defeat him with mathematical semantics.

Comment: Although the standard definition is the recurrence relation, any given implementation could use the closed form (even though this one doesn't), so this wouldn't be a sound argument for implementation questions.

Answer (score 2):

For this to be recursive function, it needs to be both recursive and a function.  As sepp2k points out, it's clearly recursive because the name `fib` appears on both sides of the `=`.  That is, `fib` is defined in terms of itself.

Is it a function?  Not according to its type.  In haskell, we call a 0-argument function "data".  So this definition of `fib` creates a recursive data structure, but not a recursive function.

Comment: `fib` is a *not* a recursive data structure in this case: "recursive data structure" means something entirely different in Haskell. `fib` is an infinite, non-repeating (and hence non-recursive) data structure generated by a recursive function (`zipWith`).

Answer (score 1):

I think there is a pretty huge reason to NOT consider this definition a recursive function (which many of the other answers seem to be missing?!), that is directly relevant to how this definition is able to achieve O(n) performance.

You can define an almost identical recursive function (that just ignores the argument) which calculates Fibonacci numbers like so:

```hs
fib :: () -> [Integer]
fib _ = 0 : 1 : zipWith (+) (fib ()) (tail $ fib ())
```

This might even be how you would consider translating this definition of `fib` into a language without knot-tying.

However, if you actually try this out, you will realise is WAY SLOWER than the non-function version.

This is because of Haskell's call-by-need semantics. When `fib` is simply a list of integers that is defined in terms of itself, `fib` directly points to a list of integers, at the end of which is an unevaluated thunk. The recursion is literally pointing back to the start of the same list. This means any work evaluating this list further inherently gets reused when computing new terms, as desired.

The function version instead will actually CALL itself, and redo all the work, on every recursive call. Haskell does not do any sort of automatic memoisation so this will have the awful O(2^n) time complexity associated with naive definitions of `fib`.

Answer (score -1):

Although many people in the comments are arguing whether or not the definition is a function, but everyone seems to agree that it is recursive.

As for the function/nonfunction argument, in Haskell, from the programmer's point of view, IT DOESN'T MATTER! Because both functions and data structures are evaluated lazily, a value and a function of no arguments returning a value are indistinguishable. What you have is a list of integers, evaluated lazily and recursively. `fib` is simultaneously a "list of integers", a "function of no arguments returning a list of integers", a "list of functions of no arguments returning integers", and "a function of no arguments returning a list of functions of no arguments returning integers".

It honestly does not matter. The language makes no distinction between the four. Type theory makes no distinction between the four (and countless others: a function of no arguments returning any of those is equally valid, as is a function of no arguments returning that, ad infinitum). It honestly makes no difference whether or not you call `fib` a "function" or not.

But it is recursive.